# How to avoid the loading of Google jsapi blocks the web page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, google-api

We have a GWT web application which used Google jsapi and jquery as well.

In the index.html, we have loaded the Google jsapi as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

However, this seems will hanging the loading of web page until it's timeout when the client is unable to access Google. In some country, for example, China.

I have changed the above script element as follows, not quite sure that is this correct or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true
});
</script>
```

And try to block myself client so it is unable to access www.google.com, however, when loading the page, it still pending for loading jsapi. I have check the network log of browser console, there are two **Initiators** as below

```
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:127
(anonymous function)    @   (index):18
```

Of cause, the index:18 is above script element. But I don't understand that about the jquery.min.js:127, which I included from local in index.html as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This jquery.min.js is jQuery v1.4.2 as this [link](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js), but it looks like there has no google jsapi loading at the line 127?

Comment: Not really an answer because I think my issue is slightly different, but I had similar behaviour in that the page was hanging on a blank page. It was because I'd wrapped google.load in a jQuery $(document).ready handler, it needs to be a top level script. Hope that helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [GWT AjaxLoader](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt.google-apis/gwt-ajaxloader/1.1.0). With this you don't have to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

to your HTML. You can execute the jsapi loading in the GWT Java Code. This for example would load the search module:

```
AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
//add options if you want to
AjaxLoader.loadApi("search", "1", new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do what you like
    }
}, options);
```

I don't experience any lag of loading using this approach.